# MVC URL re-writing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have Login  action method in my home controller like this

```
 [HttpGet]        
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

I am having this Action method as start page of my application, however I want to re-write it like this
www.abc.com/MySite/security/login

I write this attribute after [HttpGet]

```
   [Route("MySite/security/Login")]
```

Now the problem is,when I am running the application,its giving me error

```
The resource cannot be found.
```

This is my RoutConfig

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

            routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Default" ,
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}" ,
           defaults: new { controller = "Home" , action = "Login" , id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );


        }
```

How can I fix this issue,Also I am having same name method with HttpPost attribute,should I have to write Rout Attribute on it as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the work:

```
[RoutePrefix("MySite/Security")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("Login")]
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml");
        }
    }
```

EDITED:

There is one way, but I'm not sure if it's the best way. You need to create another controller called DefaultController like this:

```
public class DefaultController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Default/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
           return RedirectToAction("Login","Home");
        }
    }
```

In your RouteConfig.cs, change the 'Default' route with this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

This should do the job. I'm still trying to find other better ways.

Comment: What about Post Attribute Action method?

Comment: I edited my answer. You can add both Get and Post attributes in an action I've checked this at my end and it's working.

Comment: One more thing,my controller name is Home,not security

Comment: yes, the MapRoute code takes care of mapping HomeController to Security.

Comment: I've modified my answer. Used a different approach. This should do the work. You won't need to include RouteConfig.cs code in this case.

Comment: Thanks,its working just one concern, I have Index Action result in my Controller,where I am redirecting after login and the default Action should be login, in this case,I am running the application and its giving me error The resource cannot be found, when I am writing only www.abc.com

Comment: I want it to redirect to login page if I write www.abc.com in URL

Comment: I've added my code in the EDITED section. Please review and let me know if that worked.

Comment: Yes this can be a solution,OK I am accepting your answer,but if u find some more better approach,please edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

First, you should add custom route on the top of a default route, since you have 2 action methods with different HTTP protocols and want to make custom routing with same action name.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    // custom route
    routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Login",
           url: "MySite/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Security", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    // default route
    routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Default",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Home" , action = "Index" , id = UrlParameter.Optional }
   );
   }
```

Note that your controller with `Login` method should be named `SecurityController`, then you can set attribute routing like this code:

```
// set all default prefix to /Security path
[RoutePrefix("Security")]
public class SecurityController : Controller
{
    [Route("Login")]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Additionally, make sure you already registered the route in Global.asax file.

Any improvements & suggestions welcome.